# Having trouble with case in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, case

Im trying to get all the numbers in my table, starting with a certain number. But sometimes my system save numbers wrong, and puts 1234 in front of the real number.
So if the number looks like this: 65451, sometimes the systems makes it look like this: 123465451

Im trying to remove the first 4 chars and then just use the leftovers.

```
Select *
from Table_name

           WHERE Number = (CASE
                           WHEN SUBSTR (Number, 0, 4) = '1234' THEN SUBSTR (Number, 5)
                           ELSE
                              TO_CHAR (Number)
                        END)
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having?

Comment: This code is not delivering any numbers at all

Comment: @HansAndersen - Your code is giving me [expected output](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0adfa/5).

Comment: If im searching on numbers that starts with '1234', and then beneath tries to do the case, its not returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to fix the numbers? If so, this will do the trick:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET Number = SUBSTR(Number, 5)
WHERE Number LIKE '1234%';
```

But you should really be focusing on how the leading digits got there in the first place. There's no guarantee they won't come back.

If you're trying to query the numbers without the prefix, similar logic applies:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN Number LIKE '1234%' THEN SUBSTR(Number, 5) ELSE Number END AS GoodNumber
FROM table_name
```

**Addendum**: based on comments, the request is to find all rows which have the prefix and return the value without the prefix, which can be done as follows:

```
SELECT
  SUBSTR(Number, 5)
FROM table_name
WHERE Number LIKE '1234%'
```

Comment: I have predefined the table to put these extra numbers on. So I know for sure that they will appear again. ANd it has to be in the where clause and not in the select.

Comment: The `WHERE` clause has to return a logical (true/false) value. Your example basically returns the "fixed" number, which MySQL will interpret as `false` if the number is zero (or blank) or `true` otherwise. Are you trying to query all rows where `Number` starts with `1234`?

Comment: Yeah. I want to find the numbers starting with 1234, and then remove it. But it should only be in this statement.

Comment: I think I understand now. I've updated my answer. Can you check the last query in the answer and let me know if that's what you need?